# Starting sencha touch

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, sencha-touch

I need some guidance from you all.. I want to start making iphone/ipad apps using Sencha Touch
but i dunno HTML,javascript,XML or CSS.

Is there any book or tutorials available for the startup???

Is it mandatory to be master in javascript or HTML or CSS to use sencha touch???

Comment: Work on your HTML/CSS, javascript skills and then address Sencha Touch. It is pretty much required you know those other technologies.

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess, you're attending Senchacon right now?

Sencha Touch is based on ExtJS, which has a notoriously steep learning curve. ExtJS 4 will simplify things a bit, so maybe Sencha Touch is also more newbie friendly.

Here's the startup guide: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html

Here's the docs: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/

No XML needed. Strong understanding of HTML, Javascript, and CSS are highly recommended but not absolutely required if you have a programming background.

Comment: The truth is m good in Obj C :P

But i want to create a CMS app for IPad,thst's why i was asking .... :-s

Comment: I've seen several Apps like FlipBoard,WiredMag,etc...

Can i create such kind of App with OBJ C???

Comment: Ohmygawd. “Can i create such kind of App with OBJ C???” your errant capitalisation and intense overuse of the question-mark are disheartening.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did :

Goto this link : http://vimeo.com/channels/sencha

Start with the videos in the following order :

1. Layouts
2. Tabs & Toolbars
3. Forms

By now you should be relatively comfortable in the Framework. Explore !! Cheers

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to learn HTML, CSS, XML and Javascript is to go through the tutorials provided by [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) they provide a quick and efficent tutorials with an example for everything you needed ..................

Comment: Please dont link/refer to w3schools.com as a reference. It is possibly the worst reference as its not standards complaint. See this: http://w3fools.com/